# Building OpenCV library with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012

Has anyone been able to build OpenCV library using Visual Studio 2012?

I am specifically interested in seeing it work on Windows 8 on ARM.

Comment: The latest release compiles fine for x84 and x64. Not sure about ARM.

Comment: The latest release as in 2.4.3 or just something off the live branch?

Comment: The latest is 2.4.3.1, but 2.4.3 should be also Ok.

Comment: I tried building for Windows 8 Store apps.  Which means I can use only the Windows API available for Store apps.  Which means I had to set the following macro: WINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_APP.  And I was able to compile most of it (with some changes) for x86.  But, for ARM, I didn't succeed at all.  VS complains that I cannot build desktop applications for ARM.  I don't want to build a Desktop application.  My intention is to use this library in a Store app.  So my question is, when can we expect the relevant OpenCV CMake etc. changes to be able to build OpenCV for use inside an ARM Store app?

Comment: Btw, it looks like the real problem is with CMake not supporting the subtle differences of Windows 8 Store projects for Visual Studio 2012, especially when building for ARM.  This CMake bug report is the most recent one: http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=13511

Comment: I have added some instructions for building using VC++ 2012 for x86/x64 especially for use inside Windows 8 Store apps at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065370/using-opencv-in-a-windows-8-store-app-with-visual-c-2012

Comment: More details about this are now at this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065370/using-opencv-in-a-windows-8-store-app-with-visual-c-2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Important aspects of this question (the part about building the library using Visual C++ 2012 and using it for Windows 8) are addressed in the following question:

[Using OpenCV in a Windows Store app with Visual C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065370/using-opencv-in-a-windows-8-store-app-with-visual-c-2012)