# Rectifiy image of DVD cover

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, edge-detection, writeablebitmap, writeablebitmapex

I'm trying to get the cover image of a DVD as a rectangular image from a photo. Now as the cover on the photo  is usually a bit skewed I need to rectify it programmatically.
I've already removed most of the surroundings using the Laplacian of Gauss filter, but now I need to find the borders of the cover and somehow fill the whole frame with the coverimage.
I thought of using the Hough-Transformation, but this seems to be pretty brute-force for linking edges. I want to run this on a Windows RT Device (Surface), so a low-level idea for C# would be great. Any ideas?

[image: DVD Cover to rectify]

Comment: This might be a better fit on the DSP Stack Exchange: http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'll also try my luck over there, thx

Comment: don't **also** try your luck over there. Take your pick. Don't cross-post.

Comment: can I move it somehow?

Comment: You could flag it for moderator attention, explaining what you want to happen. Or you can delete it here and ask it again.

Comment: k, thx. I'm gonna give it a few more hours here to see if someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into OpenCV and the [image segmentation parts](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=segmentation). After that you can perform a skew / [shear transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping) on the 2D image.

Comment: I was under the impression that OpenCV (or propably the Emgu CV wrapper) is not yet ready for WinRT / Windows Phone. Am I wrong?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065370/using-opencv-in-a-windows-8-store-app-with-visual-c-2012